# Python OGR Geometry changes Floating Points

Tags: python, ogr

I'm creating a Polygon in OGR and adding coordinates to it in Python. It is a must that my coordinates aren't allowed to change when adding, however they do and I don't understand why. Here is my example:

```
import ogr
ring = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbLinearRing)
ring.AddPoint(12.5433, 54.10064)
ring.AddPoint(12.5433026066, 54.1006582464)
ring.AddPoint(12.543312311, 54.1006489082)
ring.AddPoint(12.5433093954, 54.1006320625)
ring.AddPoint(12.5433, 54.10064)

poly = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPolygon)
poly.AddGeometry(ring)

polygon = poly.ExportToWkt()
```

Now if I print the polygon, I receive:

```
'POLYGON ((12.5433 54.10064 0,
           12.543302606599999 54.100658246400002 0,
           12.543312311 54.1006489082 0,
           12.5433093954 54.100632062499997 0,
           12.5433 54.10064 0))'
```

Clearly floating points have been added to some coordinates and I can't understand why.

```
Example: (12.5433026066, 54.1006582464) to (12.543302606599999 54.100658246400002)
```

Answer (score 3):

Numbers in any programming language [does not have "absolute" precision](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html). As they must be represented as bits in the computer hardware its precision is limited.

Anyway review this links, because maybe they can help you:

- http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gis.gdal.devel/19331
- http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2011-August/029793.html